# Apache/PHP user folders

Tags: php, apache, user-interface

I am trying to create user profiles, similar to Facebook, which creates subdirectory (you can share your profile with http://facebook.com/CUSTOMURL.

Particularly, I am trying to figure out if there is a manageable way to simulate domain name links. The way I am currently running this is via a script like this:

```
function create_user_directory($userid,$dirname=null){
        if ($this->uzr_directory_exists($userid)) {                                         
            return FALSE;                                                                   
        } else {
            if (!isset($dirname)) { 
                $dirname = $userid; 
            }
            $directory = ROOT_PATH . $dirname . "/";
            mkdir($directory);
            $handle = fopen($directory . "index.php", "w") or die("can't open file");
            $template = "<?php\n\$userid=" . $userid . ";\ninclude(\"ROOT_PATH . "templates/userProfile.php\");";
            fwrite($handle, $template) or die("can't write file");
            fclose($handle);
        }

    }
```

When someone changes their directory, I would use `rename()` to change the directory and update the server.

I have to imagine there is a better way. Any insight?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: [You should use a router](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php).

Comment: FYI *subdomain* <> *sub-directory*

Comment: As others are saying, use mod_rewrite. Actually creating directory names will overwhelm the file system pretty easily, and it opens up a slew of potential security holes. (For example, you have to make sure no one ever picks a username like `images`, if you have a directory with that name.) Also, "subdirectory" (e.g., `http://facebook.com/username`) is not the same as "subdomain" (e.g., `http://username.facebook.com/`).

Comment: Whoops, typo re: subdomain @Phil! Thanks for everyone's comments. That's exactly what I was looking for. I had a strong assumption I was doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` is the best bet for things like this.

A basic `mod_rewrite` rule you can put in a `.htaccess` file to redirect all non existing files/directories to `index.php`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

You can the just pull the URL out of `$_SERVER`.